# How to add upload script

Tags: php, image, upload

I am just a beginner and need your help.

I made an upload script (MySQL), but the image/file needs to be uploaded. I don't know where to place the upload part of the code.

This is my code:

```
     <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
         mysql_connect("xx.xx.nl","xx","xxxx") or 
      die("Kan geen verbinding maken met de server!");
     mysql_select_db("xxx") or die("Kan de ingevoerde database niet vinden");

     if ($_POST){
        // file upload code
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'test/upload/'.$_FILES['img']['name']);
        }


        $query = "INSERT INTO product (
        naam,
        id,
        titel,
        druk,
        img,
        beschrijving) 

    VALUES ('".$_POST['naam']."',
            '".$_POST['id']."',
            '".$_POST['titel']."',
            '".$_POST['druk']."',
        '".$_FILES['img']['name']."',
        '".$_POST['beschrijving']."')";


      echo $query;
      mysql_query($query) or die("Kan niet invoegen.<br>". mysql_error());
     header("location:login.php");

  exit;
    }

   ?>



<table>
    <form action='voegtoe.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>


        <tr><td>    Auteur : </td><td> <select name="naam"><option value="0">Selecteer</option>
    <?php
    include("../includes/config.php");
    $get=mysql_query("SELECT naam FROM auteurs");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
    {
    ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo($row['naam'])?>" >
    <?php echo($row['naam']) ?>
    </option>
        <?php
        }               
    ?>

</select></tr></td>

   <tr><td>  Titel : </td><td> <input style="background-color: #757474;" type="text" 

    name="titel">  </tr></td>
       <tr><td>  Druk : </td><td> <input style="background-color: #757474;" type="text" name="druk">    </tr></td>
       <tr><td>  Beschrijving : </td><td> <textarea style="background-color: #757474;"  cols="25" rows="5" name="beschrijving"></textarea>  </tr></td>
       <tr><td>  Afbeelding : </td><td> <input style="background-color: #757474;" type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png" /> </tr></td>
       <tr><td> </td><td>   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Opslaan" >   </tr></td>


        </form>
      </table>
```

CODE IS UPDATED

Comment: you can put it after mysql_query or before executing mysql_query.

Comment: I did place on several places but did not work ;( (new edit is from Maz Iqbal)

Comment: Dont use his answer, he has errors there, his code is missing twice `;`... I have fixed it.

Comment: Nice, no blanco page now. But the files are not uploading....

Comment: Also this is not good: `accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png"` - `image/jpg` doesnt exists, it has to be: `accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png"`, and also you have to do image type validation in PHP code, not in HTML...

Comment: It uploads the file name in MySQL Database, but not the file in the server folder (upload/)

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong. All the paths are right  and my apache allows uploading files

Comment: No, I'm trying some things but nothing seems to work! :(

Comment: @Legionar you have no solution?

Comment: @Koessien: try this: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'upload/x.jpg');`  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], './upload/x.jpg');`  `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], '/upload/x.jpg');`

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], '/upload/x.jpg'); twice? or once?

Comment: @Koessien: Thats three examples, try each, of course each individually.

Comment: I updated my code.. please take a look @Legionar

Comment: @Koessien: This I said is wrong, and you should not use it: `accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png"`. After this line `if ($_POST){` add this `var_dump($_FILES);` and comment here the output.

Comment: @Koessien: I have tested it, what about you? Is it working now?

Comment: @Koessien: so what was the problem?

Comment: @Legionar I moved all the files from the folder to an other folder. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use $_FILES, then upload it with `move_uploaded_file()`. And then you have to store it in your DB in `BLOB` field.

Use this tutorial - http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

PS: Why do you want to upload it to DB? Why not saving to the server?

You should store it on the server, and write path to DB:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'some_folder_with_images/'.$_FILES['img']['name']);
}
```

And then this will be your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO product (
                naam,
                id,
                titel,
                druk,
                img,
                beschrijving) 

            VALUES ('".$_POST['naam']."',
                    '".$_POST['id']."',
                    '".$_POST['titel']."',
                    '".$_POST['druk']."',
                '".$_FILES['img']['name']."',
                '".$_POST['beschrijving']."')";
```

PS: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*`.

And also change this:

```
<form action='voegtoe.php' method='POST'>
```

to

```
<form action='voegtoe.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

otherwise your files will be not uploaded.

Comment: change this: `<form action='voegtoe.php' method='POST'>` to `<form action='voegtoe.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Comment: Still blanco page :( (I did everything you said)

Comment: the folder permissions are 755

Comment: Set the folder permission to 777, and also try it again, I had there missing `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need process file upload via $_FILES variable. 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place upload code after the mysql_query but remember to put a condition and write the upload code inside the condition which will execute on the success of the mysql query otherwise the files will be uploaded even if the query has an error by any means and will increase redundant data